# Join multiple excel files into one master file using python

Tags: dataframe

Hi can anyone please help me how to merge 200 same firmat data into one files in transpose into wide format.
For example
data1.xlsx containts ID, value
data2.xlsx containts ID, value
data3.xlsx containts ID, value
.
.
.
data200.xlsx containts ID, value

what I want
Master data.xlsx that contains ID, VALUE 1, VALUE 2, VALUE 3... VALUE 200
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) concat files and builtin module to find file like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/7236458)

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pandas as pd

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
files = []

for file in onlyfiles:
    files.append(pd.read_excel(file))

pd.concat(files).to_excel("data.xlsx")
```